# Passing page control from jscript to pagemethod in the codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax

I am looking write a javascript method as such called when a dropdownlist changes value

```
function GetStuff(sender, destID){

    var dest = document.getElementById(destID);
    this.PageMethods.GetStuffs(sender, dest, null, null);
}
```

GetStuffs() is in the Codebehind as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void GetStuffs(object sender, object dest)
{
    DropDownList s = sender as DropDownList;
    DropDownList d = dest as DropDownList;

    d.Items.Add(new ListItem(s.SelectedValue));
}
```

I have a break point set at the method and alerts in the GetStuff() jscript method fire up until the PageMethod call, at which nothing happens. I have set OnSuccess and OnFailure methods up with alerts and they don't get fired.

Any thoughts? Am I doing something inherently wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Couple of items to note:

- The GetStuffs class is returning void, so OnSuccess or OnFailure will not fire
- Even if you do return something back, the control on the UI will not update because the PageMethod just returns a value to the calling javascript but does not update the UI in anyway
- You will need to handle the OnSuccess event on the client & then update the dropdown on the client
- Any change to the control on the server does not reflect on the client using PageMethods
- The other point to note is that you are passing back an object of the dropdown which is a DOM element & casting it to a Server side control. This is not possible.